# How to convert non-vectorized for loop to vectorized format?

Tags: python, vectorization

I am attempting to convert the **for loop** (below) to a vectorized format, with the aim of improving computation speed.

The values a1,b1,and c1 are all constants.

How can the for loop be converted to a vectorized format?

Note:

1. While I know converting the for loop to a vectorized format would improve efficiency, I would appreciate pointers on further improving speed by altering both the while and for loops
2. I would appreciate any reading material (or other resources) that would provide a background on converting non-vectorised code to vectorized

   ```
    T = np.zeros((int(time/dt)+2, N+1)) #setting up Temperature - Position array

    n = 0 #setting position equal to 0 (initial position)
    # Initial Condition
    T[n, :] = T0 #setting T = T0 at t=0 for all positions (initial temperature array)
    # Boundary Condition
    T[:, 0] =  T_in #setting all times at n=0 to inlet fluid temperature

    while t <= time: #running simulation until required simulation time
        for i in range(1,N): #solving for temperature at every increment
            T[n+1,i] = T[n,i] + a1*T[n,i+1] - b1*T[n,i] + c1*T[n,i-1] #using three nodes (i-1,i,i+1) at time n to solve for 
                                                                      #temperature at n+1, position i

        T[n+1,-1]  = T[n+1,-2] #setting final position temperature equal to second last temperature
        T[n+1, 0] =  T_in #resetting position 0 as inlet fluid temperature
        n = n + 1 #incrementing position
        t = t + dt #incrementing time
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
T = np.empty((int(time / dt), N + 1))  #setting up Temperature - Position array

# Initial Condition
T[0, :] = T0  
# Boundary Condition
T[:, 0] = T_in

for n in range(0, T.shape[0] - 1):
    T[n + 1, 1:N] = c1 * T[n, :N - 1] + (1 - b1) * T[n, 1:N] + a1 * T[n, 2:]
    T[n + 1, -1] = T[n + 1, -2]
```

There is no need for the `while` loop. The number of rows of the array `T` is selected in such way, that the condition `t <= time` will be satisfied as you iterate over all rows of this array anyway. I don't see an easy way to avoid the remaining `for` loop, since you are computing each row recursively.